# Ensure that a task is interruptible

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

How to ensure that my tasks are responsive to interruption when I call `Future.cancel()`?

```java
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<Boolean> future = executor.submit(task);

try {
    future.get(timeout, timeoutUnit);
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    future.cancel(true);
}
```

Comment: Read the javadoc, you can't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How to ensure that my tasks are responsive to interruption when I call Future.cancel()?

Calling `future.cancel(...)` will stop the task it has not been run yet.  If it is being run then if you use `future.cancel(true)` it will interrupt the running thread.

To stop the thread you need to test the thread interrupt flag:

```
if (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
   ...
```

And you need to handle handle `InterruptedException` appropriately.  For example:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(...);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // re-establish the interrupt condition
    Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
    // probably stop the thread
    return;
}
```

See my answer about [threads not interrupting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791361/thread-not-interrupting/9791479#9791479).

Answer (score 2):

In your `task` Runnable, make sure at different levels where you do a `interrupt` check. Something like:

```
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
    //do something
}
```

If your logic in not something like loop, then check for interrupt status right before major computation like database or web-service call.

The idea here is to keep checking interrupt status as when `future.cancel(true)` is called, it ultimately interrupts your thread running `task`. This is kind of a way to know when to terminate.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around : `while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())`