# Use ExecutorService to control thread execution time

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

I'm new to Java concurrent package and want to try ExecutorService to control the execution time of a thread.

So for a keep running thread MyThread, I want to use ExecutorService and Future class to stop it after 2 seconds.

```
public class MyThread extends Thread {

    public static int count = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.println(count++);
        }
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);  
    MyThread thread = new MyThread();
    FutureTask<String> futureTask = new FutureTask<String>(thread, "success");
    try {
        executorService.submit(futureTask).get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        System.out.println("timeout");
        e.printStackTrace();
        executorService.shutdownNow();
    }
}
```

However, the thread is still keep printing numbers after 2 seconds. How can I control the thread without changing MyThread class itself?

Comment: You have written infinite loop to print numbers. Code in that class should be modified.

Comment: I use infinite loop in order to see whether ExecutorService can stop the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main purpose of using [`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) is to *hide* how threads are created, reused and in general managed for the programmer.

Instead of creating `MyThread`, you need to implement a `Runnable`:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
  private int count = 0;
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      System.out.println(count++);
    }
  }
}
```

And, this would be how to use it:

```
Future<Void> f = executorService.submit(new MyRunnable());
f.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Regarding the termination property in the question, the example Runnable is not a good one, because it [does not provide an interruptible task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702482/ensure-that-a-task-is-interruptible). For example, if a `sleep` operation is added:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
  private int count = 0;
  public void run() {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
      System.out.println(count++);
      try {
        Thread.sleep(0, 1);
      } catch (InterruptedException x) {
        return;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thread implements Runnable. I also tried your method, Future f = executorService.submit(new MyRunnable());   f.get(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS); It still not work. The thread is still running all the time.

Comment: Maybe it's good to read a bit about the difference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541487/implements-runnable-vs-extends-thread

Comment: In addition, you cannot *always* assume that every thread is *interruptible*. You need to ensure certain properties to allow a thread to be interrupted. That's why you see the behavior you explained. Read more at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702482/ensure-that-a-task-is-interruptible

Comment: Actually, I use MyThread and change the loop while(true) to while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()). Then the thread can be interrupted. I guess unless there's a label to check thread isInterruped, the thread cannot be stopped. Thanks @nobeh

Answer (score 0):

Use [returned](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit%28java.lang.Runnable%29) [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object for control.