# How to set thread timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, scala

I have this `scala` code, which works just fine (`run()` is overridden in class)

```
val processRunnable = new myProcessClassWithOverriddenRunFunction()
val processThread = new Thread(processRunnable)
processThread.start
```

What I want to do is set a **timeout** for `processThread` thread. How can I do that?

I did some research and couldn't find any parameter we can pass to `new Thread()` or any function in `processThread` to achieve that.

Found some solutions on `stackoveflow` which implemented a `ExecutorService` but unfortunately, that is not implementable in this particular problem as making another new `ExecutorService` for just a single `processThread`, everytime this function is called seems inefficient. There are some other reasons as well but my question is how can I implement that functionality on this code?

Comment: You need to implement it in your thread yourself, so that it exits after reaching a certain run time.

Comment: @rustyx I don't understand, can you elaborate a little? Won't I need another thread to work as a timer? Where can I put a check for that timer?

Comment: Why are you writing java code in scala syntax? That seems ... counterproductive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, you can use

```
CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(processRunnable);
future.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

To `future.get` function will throw a `TimeOutException` when timeout (1 second in the example above) is reached and the timeout case can be handled in catch block.
Complete code will be something like this:

```
try {
     CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(processRunnable);
    future.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
catch{
case texc : TimeoutException => println("Timeout is reached.")
case exc  : Exception => println(exc.getmessage)
}
```

Comment: Hi @danju! thanks but I have some questions, there is no `future.getOrElse` function, where does control go if future fails? If I want to do something if future fails, where and how can I do it?

Comment: @saadi in that case, `future.get()` will throw an Exception (a `TimeoutException` if the timeout was reached, or an `ExecutionException` wrapping the underlying exception if the `run()` method threw an exception)

Comment: note that while the CompletableFuture will return after the timeout, the actual thread may still continue to run and use resources. @rustyx answer is better in this regard.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to achieve that without the thread cooperating. This is similar in nature to how to make a thread [interruptible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702482/ensure-that-a-task-is-interruptible), and has to do with the fact that it is in general [unsafe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html) to stop running threads asynchronously (and a timeout is asynchronous).

Your thread needs to include the timeout capability as part of it's implementation, so that it can act on a timeout condition when it is safe for it to do so.

For example:

```
public class MyProcessClass {
    private final long timeoutMillis = 30000;
    public void run() {
        long timeout = System.currentTimeMillis() + timeoutMillis;
        while (System.currentTimeMillis() < timeout) {
            // Process next chunk of work
        }
    }
}
```

---

PS. Don't be misled by the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275443/how-to-timeout-a-thread) based on the `ExecutorService` - it requires the thread to be interruptible, i.e. the same solution as shown above.

```
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            // Process next chunk of work
        }
```

Comment: If we rely on the `Thread.interrupted()` we may get into trouble in case we want graceful shutdown and to finish the currently executing task. In that case `PoisonPill` is a better choice.